# Get more than 1000 rows from a SQL Server SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I want to select more than 1000 rows with a `SELECT` statement. There are about 2000 rows and I want them in one `SELECT`. But I only get 1000 rows.

This is my code:

```csharp
string connection_sql = String.Concat("Server=", m_server, m_sql_db_instance, "; Database=Instances;User Id=", m_sql_user_id, "; Password=", m_sql_user_pw);

Log("Try to connect to SQL database", MessageType.Debug);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_sql))
{
    // Open SQL Connecntion
    conn.Open();
                    
    // Execute SQL statement
    string sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM [Instances].[dbo].[BI_BIT]";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_statement, conn);

    try
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return "Error in creating process";
    }

    // Close SQL Connection

    /* --- Here comes further processes --- */
}
```

If I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio, I get all rows.

How can I get all records of my table by `SELECT` (or something else) in my C# code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One can only assume you are connecting to the wrong instance, database or schema.

Comment: Why do you think you only get 1000 rows? if you debug in visual studio, it might just display some sort of top X rows.

Comment: Slight detour....you really need to read about and utilize the `USING` statement for your connections, commands and other objects implementing the iDisposable interface. Also, you should state the columns you want returned instead of *.

Comment: And note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Answer (score -4):

The issue you are facing where you only receive 1000 records is likely due to the default behavior of SqlDataAdapter. By default, SqlDataAdapter retrieves only the first 1000 rows from the result set. To fetch more than 1000 records, you can adjust the CommandTimeout property and use a DataReader instead of a DataAdapter.

```
    string connection_sql = String.Concat("Server=", m_server, m_sql_db_instance, "; Database=Instances;User Id=", m_sql_user_id, "; Password=", m_sql_user_pw);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_sql))
{
    // Open SQL Connection
    conn.Open();

    // Execute SQL-Statement
    string sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM [Instances].[dbo].[BI_BIT]";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_statement, conn);
    
    // Set command timeout (optional)
    command.CommandTimeout = 0; // 0 means no timeout, adjust as needed
    
    try
    {
        // Use SqlDataReader instead of SqlDataAdapter
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Load the data directly from the reader into the DataTable
            dataTable.Load(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error in creating process";
    }

    // Close SQL Connection
    // ...

    /* --- Here comes further processes --- */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it still return 1000 records.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. `DataTable.Load` uses a DbDataAdapter as well. SqlDataAdapter loads all rows.  Neither do timeouts affect how much data is loaded.

Comment: "By default, SqlDataAdapter retrieves only the first 1000 rows from the result set" completely incorrect and has no basis in fact.

Comment: Another "win" for Chat CPT?